# "Literal" numbering of chapters

Tags: numbering, chapters

I'm finishing a book, and I want the first page of each chapter to begin with the literal numerotation:

> Chapter one

...

> Chapter two

...

> chapter three

etc.

I've seen it in several books so I think it possible, but how?

A file example...in arabic

```
\documentclass[14pt,a4paper]{extbook}%{article}%

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{boxedminipage}
\usepackage{slashbox}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{minitoc}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{fmultico}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.1pt}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[numerals=maghrib]{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}

\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic, AutoFakeSlant=-0.02]{Amiri}
\setsansfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.5]{Amiri}

\gappto\captionsarabic{\renewcommand{\chaptername}{الباب}}
\begin{document}
\chapter{المحاكاة}
كيف يمكننا إيجاد  احتمال الفوز في  لعبة         
 \end{document}
```

Comment: You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Comment: How do you want cross-references to chapter numbers to be typeset: As numerals (arabic: 1, 2, ...; roman: i, ii, ...; alphabetic: a, b, ...) or as literal words ("One", "Two", ...)? Please advise.

Comment: I want my references numeral in arabic and the titles (and only the titles) in words "One", "Two"

Comment: Do you have code for `titlesec` or are you just loading it? If you have `\titleformat{\chapter}...`, then that's the place where action should be done.

Comment: @FaouziBellalouna see updated answer

Comment: @egreg I have the code

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}
\titlespacing{\chapter}
  {0pt}{40pt}{-10pt}

in my macros for contents.. and I don't understand what you're saying "that's the place where action should be done"..

Comment: @FaouziBellalouna Instead of `\thechapter` in `\titleformat`, use a macro like David defined, say `\words{chapter}` (and provide the definition).

Comment: @egreg Ok but in the table of contents, the numerotation is literal, except chapter 1.. After, in the contents, it's written "two", "three", "four"..etc... I want to obtain a numeric numbering in the contents, and literal numbering in the first page of the page only.

Comment: The package `titletoc` seems not to work and makes an infinite loop. From David's code use only the definition of `\words` and don't add the changes to `\@makechapterhead`.

Comment: If I don't use the change to \@makechapterhead, the numbering remains numerical not literal !

Answer (score 10):

use `\words{chapter}` instead of `\arabic{chapter}` where `words` is defined by

```
\newcommand\words[1]{\expandafter\xwords\csname c@#1\endcsname}
\def\xwords#1{\ifcase#1\or
one\or
two\or
three\else
I need more words\fi}
```

I switched fonts as I didn't have the one you used, and left the words in English:-)

[image]

```
\documentclass[14pt,a4paper]{extbook}%{article}%

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{boxedminipage}
\usepackage{slashbox}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{minitoc}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{fmultico}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.1pt}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{array}


\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[numerals=maghrib]{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}

\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic, AutoFakeSlant=-0.02]{Arial}
\setsansfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.5]{Arial}

\gappto\captionsarabic{\renewcommand{\chaptername}{الباب}}
% probably can use titlesec's \titleformat but I don't know that package:-}
\makeatletter
\let\old@makechapterhead\@makechapterhead
\def\@makechapterhead{\def\thechapter{\words{chapter}}\old@makechapterhead}
\makeatother


\newcommand\words[1]{\expandafter\xwords\csname c@#1\endcsname}
\def\xwords#1{\ifcase#1\or
one\or
two\or
three\or
four\or
five\else
I need more words\fi}




\begin{document}

\chapter{المحاكاة}
كيف يمكننا إيجاد  احتمال الفوز في  لعبة         
 \end{document}
```

Comment: After three\else, I write four\else five\else six\else seven\else eight\else nine\else ten\else after this \fi} ??

Comment: The numerotation is automatic ? so when I write \chapter{First chapter}, it writes "First chapter one" ?

Comment: No just use `\else` for the last "error" case  where you run out of words, separate all the real cases by `\or`, the chapter heading code probably defines `Chapter \arabic{chapter}` you need to change that to use `\words` instead, if it isn't clear how to change that you could ask about that but you have given no indication of your document class (questions should always include an example document for that reason)

Comment: Please see the example what I added, without commenting here...

Comment: You could take a look at the `fmtcount` package: it is dedicated to translating the value of counters into tex, and has some multilingual support.  There is no arabic support, but you might take what exists as a model.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle. All works well, tried to several chapter.. Thanks

Comment: @Bernard. I'll discover this package, and inform if I can write an application of it in arabic. Thanks

Comment: @DavidCarlisle. After more try, I have the problem of the table of contents, where the numerotation of the chapters is "literal", 1, after two, three..etc. How to apply numerical numbering in the contents ?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/640752/change-part-numbers-to-words-in-arabic?noredirect=1#comment1596944_640752