# "Literal" numbering of chapters but not in contents

Tags: table-of-contents, numbering

Thanks to this macro

```
\makeatletter
\let\old@makechapterhead\@makechapterhead
\def\@makechapterhead{\def\thechapter{\words{chapter}}\old@makechapterhead}
\makeatother


\newcommand\words[1]{\expandafter\xwords\csname c@#1\endcsname}
\def\xwords#1{\ifcase#1\or
one\or
two\or
three\or
four\or
five\else
I need more words\fi}
```

which comes from this question 
["Literal" numbering of chapters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/175425/literal-numbering-of-chapters?noredirect=1#comment406393_175425)

All feel well, and I obtain what I want in the first page of each chapter, "Chapter one", "Chapter two",...etc but in the table of contents, it uses the same numerotation of the chapters, so litteral, that I don't want, evidently. So how can I use the usual numbering (`\arabic{chapter}`) for the contents ?

Comment: It seems truely a duplication... Thks for "alert"

Answer (score 0):

It is best to use the package `fmtcount` to get the spelled out value of a counter. In this case you will need to use the `tocstyle` package to adjust the margins in the table of contents.

If you want to use this for chapters, just replace every occurrence of `section` by `chapter`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}% for cropping
\usepackage{fmtcount,tocstyle}
\renewcommand\thesection{\Numberstring{section}}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{First section}
\section{Second section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\section{Third section}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Hello, I use the package titlesec and the solution you propose produces a conflict with this package.

Comment: I don't get any conflicts, when I just `\usepackage{titlesec}`. Can you elaborate?

Comment: I give an example of  file

Comment: \documentclass[14pt,a4paper]{extbook}

  \usepackage{titlesec}
  \usepackage{titletoc}
  \usepackage{etoolbox}
  \usepackage{multicol}
  \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
  \usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
  \usepackage{boxedminipage}
  \usepackage{slashbox}
  \usepackage{titlesec}
  \usepackage{enumitem}
  \usepackage{minitoc}
  \usepackage{rotating}
  \usepackage{fmultico}
  \setlength{\columnseprule}{0.1pt}
  \usepackage{fancyhdr}
  \pagestyle{fancy}
  \usepackage{pdflscape}
  \usepackage{array}

Comment: \usepackage{polyglossia}
  \setmainlanguage[numerals=maghrib]{arabic}
  \setotherlanguage{english}

  \newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic, AutoFakeSlant=-0.02]{Traditional Arabic}
     \setsansfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.5]{Traditional Arabic}

  \usepackage{MyBoxes}
  \usepackage{MyRoss}


  \gappto\captionsarabic{\renewcommand{\chaptername}{الباب}}
  % probably can use titlesec's \titleformat but I don't know that package:-}

  \makeatletter
  \let\old@makechapterhead\@makechapterhead
  \def\@makechapterhead{\def\thechapter{\words{chapter}}\old@makechapterhead}
  \makeatother

Comment: \newcommand\words[1]{\expandafter\xwords\csname c@#1\endcsname}
  \def\xwords#1{\ifcase#1\or
  الأول\or   
الثاني\or   
الثالث\or   
الرابع\or   
الخامس\or   
السادس\or   
السابع\or   
الثامن\or   
التاسع\or   
العاشر\or   
   \else
   I need more words\fi}




  \begin{document}
  \tableofcontents
  \chapter{المحاكاة}
  \section{مقدمة} %sec10.1

كيف يمكننا إيجاد  احتمال الفوز في  لعبة   
السوليتير؟   
  \chapter{المحاكاة}
كيف يمكننا إيجاد  احتمال الفوز في  لعبة  من الباب     
   \end{document}

Comment: This is an example of my file. It gives me chapters "one" and "two" in the first pages of chapters, and in the contents "1" and "two". I want to obtain the same thing in the text but, in the contents, "1" and "two"

Comment: After removing all the packages unnecessary to the problem (BTW: you were loading `titlesec` twice) and using an arabic font I have installed it compiles for me without any problem. The other problem is, that I can't read arabic and therefore can't tell if there is a problem with the output.

Comment: It's not a problem of arabic... I give you another example without arabic.. I want that the numbering is "literal", i.e. "one" "two" etc.. but for the chapterhead I want it numeric... 1.1 for the section 1 not one.1 like in the contents...

Comment: \documentclass[14pt,a4paper]{extbook}

  \usepackage{titletoc}
  \usepackage{etoolbox}
  \usepackage{multicol}
  \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
  \usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
  \usepackage{boxedminipage}
  \usepackage{slashbox}
  \usepackage{titlesec}
  \usepackage{enumitem}
  \usepackage{minitoc}
  \usepackage{rotating}
  \usepackage{fmultico}
  \setlength{\columnseprule}{0.1pt}
  \usepackage{fancyhdr}
  \pagestyle{fancy}
  \usepackage{pdflscape}
  \usepackage{array}

  \usepackage{polyglossia}
  \setmainlanguage{english}
  \setotherlanguage[numerals=maghrib]{arabic}

Comment: \makeatletter
  \let\old@makechapterhead\@makechapterhead
  \def\@makechapterhead{\def\thechapter{\words{chapter}}\old@makechapterhead}
  \makeatother


  \newcommand\words[1]{\expandafter\xwords\csname c@#1\endcsname}
  \def\xwords#1{\ifcase#1\or
  one\or   
  two\or   
  three\or   
   \else
   I need more words\fi}




  \begin{document}
  \tableofcontents
  \chapter{Simulation}
  \section{Introduction 1} 
  Simulation
  \section{Introduction 2} 
  \chapter{Simulation}
    Simulation
   \end{document}

Comment: I write all the packages for preventing eventual conflicts because I use all this packages in my book (of probability in arabic)