# Change chapter numbers to words in Arabic

Tags: chapters, arabic

Instead of "Chapter 1" I want "Chapter one", but in Arabic.
one => الأول and so on.

In english, a solution exist:

```
\usepackage{fmtcount,etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\thechapter}{\Numberstring{chapter}}{}{}
\patchcmd{\chaptermark}{\thechapter}{\NUMBERstring{chapter}}{}{}
\makeatother
```

But what about Arabic? MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,english]{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[numerals=maghrib]{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.5]{Arabic Typesetting}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{arabic}
\chapter{مقدمة}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know if this is too late but here is a solution to your problem based on this answer:
[“Literal” and numerical numbering of chapters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/176203/literal-and-numerical-numbering-of-chapters) and this one too ["Literal" numbering of chapters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/175425/literal-numbering-of-chapters)

This MWE supports up to 20 chapters but of course you can easily add more chapter numbers in words:

```
\documentclass[12pt,english]{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[numerals=maghrib]{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.5]{Arabic Typesetting}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\gappto\captionsarabic{\renewcommand{\chaptername}{الباب}} %to name the chapter title   الباب instead of باب
\newcommand\words[1]{\expandafter\xwords\csname c@#1\endcsname}
\def\xwords#1{\ifcase#1\or
الأول\or          
الثاني\or          
الثالث\or 
الرابع\or 
الخامس\or 
السادس\or 
السابع\or 
الثامن\or 
التاسع\or 
العاشر\or 
الحادي عشر\or 
الثاني عشر\or 
الثالث عشر\or 
الرابع عشر\or 
الخامس عشر\or 
السادس عشر\or  
السابع عشر\or
الثامن عشر\or 
التاسع عشر\or 
العشرون\or 

    \else
    أحتاج إلى المزيد من ترقيمات الأبواب بالحروف في ملف arbbook.cls\fi}
%next three lines is to make chapter naming use the above wordings (literal numbering in Arabic words)

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\thechapter}{\words{chapter}}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{arabic}
\chapter{مقدمة}
\end{document}
```

This outputs:

**الباب الأول**

Comment: Forgot to remove my class name arbbook.cls. But anyway, that line actually is useless. It only acts as a warning. to the MWE will work correctly anyway.

Comment: While I have solved the problem using another solution, yours indeed is a solution to the question asked.

Comment: There is a small error @Ahmed-El-Bokl, the third ordinal number is repeated. Otherwise your solution helped me a lot.

Comment: @Tim yes you are right. Thank you for pointing that out. I fixed it.

Comment: Is there any way to do the same with the Part
I tried to use the command \gappto\captionsarabic{\renewcommand{\partname}{القــسم}} which works pretty much good to change the Part name, but the ordinal numbering does not change with \patchcmd{\@makeparthead}{\thepart}{\wordp{part}}{}{}. What should be patched or modified ? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, please I am having the same issue with Part as @Kais mentioned.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/640752/change-part-numbers-to-words-in-arabic?noredirect=1#comment1596944_640752