# title spacing using titlesec and customisation

Tags: sectioning, chapters, titlesec

I am using some code from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/176858/change-chapter-numbers-to-words-in-arabic) which allows me to use ordinal numbers in arabic for the chapter titles.

I also want to change the title spacing.  I am only a little familiar with `titlesec`.  The `\titlespacing` command requires an earlier setting of `\titleformat` (page 5 of `titlesec` documentation) but I don't know how to incorporate the `patchcmd` in the MWE inside the  `\titleformat` format command.

How can I use `titlesec` as well as my arabic ordinal numbers?
The commented-out line in the MWE is the setting I would like for my title spacing.

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{report}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[numerals=mashriq]{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Times New Roman}

\gappto\captionsarabic{\renewcommand{\chaptername}{الباب}} 
\newcommand\words[1]{\expandafter\xwords\csname c@#1\endcsname}
\def\xwords#1{\ifcase#1\or
الأول\or          
الثاني\or          
الثالث\or 
الرابع\or 
الخامس\or 
    \else
    you need to supply additional numbers \fi}
%next three lines is to make chapter naming use the above wordings (literal numbering in Arabic words)
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\thechapter}{\words{chapter}}{}{}
\makeatother

% \titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{0ex plus 9ex minus 9ex}{0ex plus 9ex minus 9ex}

\begin{document}
\chapter{ددد}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What happens if you load `titlesec` after the patch?

Comment: `titlesec` must be before `polyglossia`, and `polyglossia` must be before the patch.  But even apart from this, the `\titlespacing` command has no effect unless i issue a `\titleformat` command, which I don't know how to do with the ordinal patch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here two solutions, with and without `titlesec` package

**First** (`titlesec`)

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{report}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[numerals=mashriq]{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Times New Roman}

\gappto\captionsarabic{\renewcommand{\chaptername}{الباب}} 
\def\xwords#1{\ifcase\value{#1}\or
الأول\or          
الثاني\or          
الثالث\or 
الرابع\or 
الخامس\or 
    \else
    you need to supply additional numbers \fi}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \xwords{chapter}}{20pt}{\Huge}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{0ex plus 9ex minus 9ex}{0ex plus 9ex minus 9ex}

\begin{document}
\chapter{ددد}
\end{document}
```

**second**

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{report}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[numerals=mashriq]{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Times New Roman}

\gappto\captionsarabic{\renewcommand{\chaptername}{الباب}} 
\def\xwords#1{\ifcase\value{#1}\or
الأول\or          
الثاني\or          
الثالث\or 
الرابع\or 
الخامس\or 
    \else
    you need to supply additional numbers \fi}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\thechapter}{\xwords{chapter}}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\vspace*{50\p@}}{\vspace*{0ex plus 9ex minus 9ex}}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\vskip 40\p@}{\vspace*{0ex plus 9ex minus 9ex}}{}{}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\chapter{ددد}
\end{document}
```